# Is storing password hashes in plain text dangerous?

Tags: linux, security, chef

We have a server that is going to be managed through a chef cookbook.  Each user for the system is configured using hashes from /etc/shadow.

Can we safely store these shadow hashes in our version-control system, allowing users to easily change their passwords, or must they be stored in a more secure encrypted data bag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you've got an up to date version of linux /etc/shadow should be fine. See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772014/is-sha-1-secure-for-password-storage